# How to get all streets from pbf for one city using SQL?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, sql

I have a file russia-latest.osm.pbf, which is imported into postgreSQL in default form and with hstore support.

For example, I get a list of all cities, where the population is more than 200 000 people by query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM planet_osm_point
  WHERE (place = 'town' OR place = 'city')
    AND CASE WHEN population ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN population::int > 200000 ELSE false END;
```

Can you please tell me which query to run to get the names of all the streets that are in the city of “Krasnodar”?